# Which pins should I use to connect a watch crystal for powering a low frequency crystal oscillator in ATmega328p?

Tags: avr, crystal, atmel, atmega328p

If I want use a watch crystal(32KHz) with the low frequency crystal oscillator of an ATmega328p, which pin should I connect the crystal to?

Should I connect the crystal to XTAL1,XTAL2 pins of ATmega328p, or should I connect the crystal to TOSC1,TOSC2** pins of ATmega328p?

Answer (score 1):

The XTAL pins are also the TOSC pins, so you really don't have an option to go wrong here.

Comment: Are you saying that XTAL pins and TOSC pins are internally connected and i can connect the crystal to either XTAL pins or TOSC pins to use the LOW Frequency Crystal Oscillator

Comment: Just look at the MCU pins on datasheet. You will find that TOSC pins are same as XTAL pins.

Answer (score 1):

A 32.768 kHz crystal is a crystal and needs to be connected to the "Low-frequency
crystal Oscillator" which is connected to the TOSC1 and TOSC2 pins.

Which are the same pins as the XTAL1 and XTAL2 pins!

Are you confused yet?

The **function** of these pins is defined by the settings defined by the **clock selection fuses**. These are discussed in section 6.2 of the [datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/SMD/ATMega328.pdf).

So you might have to (re)program the "fuses" to allow the 32 kHz crystal to be used.

Also realize that at a 32 kHz clock the MCU will operate quite slowly.

If you want to make a clock using an MCU, consider a dedicated RTC (Real Time clock) module like the DS1307.

Comment: Also of note, you can dynamically change the clock settings in code when the MCU boots rather than burning fuses. If the MCU is being clocked externally at such a low speed, you will also likely have to add a -B 1024 option to AVRDUDE programming commands to change the communication bitrate.